# New to self-hosting and struggling with Monica CRM Docker setup (503 Error)

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, self-hosting

As someone new to self-hosting, I embarked on what I thought would be a relatively simple project: setting up Monica CRM using Docker. However, I've encountered an unexpected challenge and am seeking assistance from those with more experience.

**Background:**

This is my first foray into self-hosting, and my knowledge of Docker and Nginx is quite basic.
I am facing a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" error when trying to access Monica CRM through the browser.

**Setup:**

The setup is based on Monica CRM using Docker Compose, with the files taken from the example folder in the official repository.
The services included are app (Monica), db (MariaDB), redis, cron, queue, web, proxy (Nginx), and a Let's Encrypt companion container.
Nginx is set up as a reverse proxy to handle web requests.
Issue:

I am consistently getting a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" error, even though the services seem to be up and running.
The Monica app service (app) is internally using port 9000, but there are no external ports exposed in the docker-compose.yml.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Confirmed the status of all services using docker-compose ps.
Reviewed the Nginx configuration, ensuring the upstream directive is correctly set to server app:9000.
Checked Docker networking to ensure the Monica app and Nginx proxy can communicate internally.
Double-checked the .env file for correct environment variables.
Restarted all services after making any configuration changes.

Here are key snippets of my docker-compose.yml and Nginx configuration for context:

```
services:   app:
    build: ./app
    image: monica-app
    ...   proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    ...
```

Nginx configuration:

```
nginx Copy code upstream php-handler {
    server app:9000; }
```

I anticipated a smooth start to self-hosting with Monica CRM, but I've found myself stuck quite early in the process.